# Files remain open/locked in Azure Function - unable to delete

Tags: java, azure, azure-functions

My program makes use of a [library](https://github.com/kikovalle/PLGSharepointRestAPI-java) to upload a file located in an Azure File Share to Sharepoint, after which the file is deleted from Azure File Share. Below is a small (the relevant) part of my code; when I run it the file is uploaded correctly, but isn't removed afterwards isn't removed because it is still in use by an SMB client (it's "marked for deletion", but is only deleted once the Azure Function is disabled).

My guess was that since an InputStream is opened in the wrapper.uploadFile, but not closed that might be it, but `resource.isOpen()` always returns `false`

**main.class**

```
    File file = new File (filepath);
    Resource resource = new FileSystemResource(filepath);
    PLGSharepointClient wrapper = new PLGSharepointClient(user, passwd, domain, spSiteUrl);   
    JSONObject jsonMetadata = new JSONObject();
    wrapper.uploadFile(spFolder, resource, jsonMetadata);
    
    resource.getInputStream().close();
    System.out.println(resource.isOpen());
    file.delete();
```

**wrapper.uploadFile**

```
    public JSONObject uploadFile(String folder, Resource resource, JSONObject jsonMetadata) throws Exception {
            LOG.debug("Uploading file {} to folder {}", resource.getFilename(), folder);
            JSONObject submeta = new JSONObject();
            submeta.put("type", "SP.ListItem");
            jsonMetadata.put("__metadata", submeta);
            
            headers = headerHelper.getPostHeaders("");
            headers.remove("Content-Length");
            
            byte[] resBytes = IOUtils.readFully(resource.getInputStream(), (int) resource.contentLength());
     
            RequestEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new RequestEntity<>(resBytes, 
                headers, HttpMethod.POST, 
                this.tokenHelper.getSharepointSiteUrl(
                        "/_api/web/GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl('" + UriUtils.encodeQuery(folder, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) +"')/Files/add(url='" 
                        + UriUtils.encodeQuery(resource.getFilename(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "',overwrite=true)"
                        )
                );
    
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = 
                restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity, String.class);
    
            String fileInfoStr = responseEntity.getBody();
            
            LOG.debug("Retrieved response from server with json");
            
            JSONObject jsonFileInfo = new JSONObject(fileInfoStr);
            String serverRelFileUrl = jsonFileInfo.getJSONObject("d").getString("ServerRelativeUrl");
    
            LOG.debug("File uploaded to URI", serverRelFileUrl);
            String metadata = jsonMetadata.toString();
            headers = headerHelper.getUpdateHeaders(metadata);
    
            LOG.debug("Updating file adding metadata {}", jsonMetadata);
    
            RequestEntity<String> requestEntity1 = new RequestEntity<>(metadata, 
                headers, HttpMethod.POST, 
                this.tokenHelper.getSharepointSiteUrl("/_api/web/GetFileByServerRelativeUrl('" + UriUtils.encodeQuery(serverRelFileUrl, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + "')/listitemallfields")
                );
            ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity1 = 
                    restTemplate.exchange(requestEntity1, String.class);
            LOG.debug("Updated file metadata Status {}", responseEntity1.getStatusCode());
            return jsonFileInfo;
        }
```

Comment: file.delete(); - is this true?

Answer (score 0):

In your wrapper.upload file, add `resource.getInputStream().close()` and check if this works.

Comment: I checked it in my system, it worked. Then, maybe the SMB client you are using is keeping the stream open. Can you try disposing PLGSharepointClient?